# Nested cursors with mongodb driver in phoenix/elixir

Tags: mongodb, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using the mongodb driver from https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb to query a mongodb database in an elixir/phoenix project. In another question, I asked about how to query nested jsons. Another issue would be how to query inserted documents. For example, I can do the following in python

```
date_=db['posts']['name'][name]['date'][date]
```

Here, 'posts' is the name of the collection, and the others are inserted documents. For example, one 'date' document was inserted through:

```
  db['posts']['name'][name].insert_one({"date":date})
```

When I want to obtain all the inserted dates in python, I can do

```
date_list=[]
def get_date(db):
  db_posts_name=db['posts']['name'][name]
  for date_query in db_posts_name.find():
        date_list.append(date_query["date"])
```

But I am at a loss in elixir/phoenix to do the same thing because if I do something like

```
      list =
        :mongo
        |> Mongo.find("posts", %{})
        |> Enum.fetch(4)
        |> elem(1) 
        |> Map.fetch("name")
        |> elem(1)
      new_list =
        :mongo
        |> Mongo.find("posts", %{"name" => list})
      another_list=new_list.find("date",%{})
```

I get error

```
Called with 3 arguments

%Mongo.Cursor{coll: "posts", conn: #PID<0.434.0>, opts: [slave_ok: true], query: %{"name" => name}, select: nil}
:find
[]
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Could you please share the minimal viable data and what do you expect to get back as a result? The current code issue is `new_list.find` notation (there are _no_ objects in [tag:elixir], one cannot use dot notation on anything, one should call the functions from modules, passing terms as an argument.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking that `new_list.find()` is a function call to the cursor, just as in the python code above.

Answer (score 0):

`Mongo.find` returns always a cursor. A cursor is like a streaming api, so you have to
call some function like `Enum.take()` or `Enum.to_list`. If you processing very long collections
it is a good idea to use the `Stream` module instead.

If you want to fetch one document, then you can use `Mongo.find_one`.

I'm not understanding your example. I assume `name` is a parameter:

```py
  date_list=[]
  def get_date(db):
    db_posts_name=db['posts']['name'][name]
    for date_query in db_posts_name.find():
          date_list.append(date_query["date"])
```

The following code fetches in collection `posts` all documents which `name` is equal to the parameter `name` and returns only the `date` field:

```
    date_list = :mongo
      |> Mongo.find("posts", %{"name" => name}, %{"date" => 1})    
      |> Enum.map(fn %{"date" => date} -> date end)
```

By the way you can give [elixir-mongodb-driver](https://github.com/zookzook/elixir-mongodb-driver) a try. This implementation supports the bulk api, change streams api and the transaction api as well.